# A better way to get thread ID than pthread_self or gettid

Tags: linux, pthreads

My question is if there is a function which returns thread ID other than **pthread_self** and **gettid**. The problem with **pthread_self** is that it returns an address while **gettid** returns system wide global tid. I want relative thread id, so thread ids should be 0, 1, 2, 3, etc and not addresses as in case of **pthread_self**.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't. If you really need it (which I doubt), implement your own mechanism.

- Declare a global `static int thread_count;`
- Declare a global `static __thread int my_thread_id;`
- When a thread starts, lock a mutex and assign the id

Here's an example:

```
static int thread_count;
static __thread int my_thread_id;
static pthread_mutex_t start_mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

static void *th_function(void *arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&start_mtx);
       my_thread_id = thread_count++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&start_mtx);
    /* rest of function */
}
```

Obviously you could also use thread-specific data (`pthread_setspecific` etc) (which is standard).